# Nodejs SIGINT not working as expected when using Puppeteer

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I'm using puppeteer in my nodejs project which has `SIGINT` event as defined as below:

```js
function handleQuit() {
    // report process exit to backend for the ongoing jobs
    let promises = requests.map((id)=>{
        return steps.report({id},'worker.closed', 'error', 'process closed');
    });
    Promise.all(promises).then(()=>{
        process.exit(0);
    });
}
process.on('SIGINT', handleQuit);
process.on('SIGTERM', handleQuit);
process.on('SIGQUIT', handleQuit);
```

The `handleQuit` function gets called, but for some reason when `puppeteer` gets initialized my process gets closed immediately after `SIGINT` is triggered and i don't have the chance to finish calling the backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puppeteer handles `SIGINT` by default, that's why the code doesn't behave like you think it would after puppeteer gets initialized.

Luckily you can disable this feature in the launch options as described in the [docs](https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.launchoptions):

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  handleSIGINT: false,
  handleSIGHUP:false,
  handleSIGTERM: false,
});
```

Now your `handleQuit` function is the only function which is responsible to handle `SIGINT`.